# How to manage dependency registration in NopCommerce 3.90 depending upon plugin installed or not?

Tags: nopcommerce, nopcommerce-3.90

I have created one plugin, in that I am overriding some methods from `ProductService` (and more). For that I have registered my `CustomProductServie` to `IProductService`.

While my Plugin is installed, it is working fine but after uninstalling the plugin.  it is overriding `ProductService` methods. (NopCommerce 3.90)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check using plugin description name as follows,

```
var pluginDescriptor = _pluginFinder.GetPluginDescriptorBySystemName("PluginSystemName");
```

If `pluginDescriptor`is null, plugin is not installed. Also note, you need to add reference of `IPluginFinder` interface in your class.

Comment: Glad I could help.